# CSV not working for Rails 3 in Production using passenger

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, passenger, production

I currently have a problem where i am exporting some data and generating a CSV in rails3. In my controller i add the following at the top.

```
require 'CSV'
```

I then have my method that generates the CSV file.
In development i am able to generate and download the csv file just fine but in production mode, passenger returns me the following error.

```
No such file to load -- CSV
```

wondering if anyone has had this issue because i thought the CSV library included in ruby 1.9.2, i am not using any gems for creating a CSV file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it is **csv** instead of **CSV**:

```
require 'csv'
```