# Error H10 crashing Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm afraid I'm totally at a loss for why my rails app is crashing on Heroku. It's working fine on my development environment, and I can't see anything obvious in the logs. What am I missing?

Here is the Heroku log:

```
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:33240
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- CSV (LoadError)
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-08-16T19:19:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-08-16T19:19:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-16T19:19:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-16T19:19:16+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-08-16T19:19:16+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-08-16T19:19:37+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET fierce-tor-1874.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-16T19:19:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET fierce-tor-1874.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-16T19:19:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET fierce-tor-1874.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-16T19:19:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET fierce-tor-1874.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
Ashers-MacBook-Pro%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wrote

```
gem 'CSV'
```

in Gemfile ? It should be downcase: `gem 'csv'`.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132180/csv-not-working-for-rails-3-in-production-using-passenger)